# IntelliJ: Highlight patterns in output of JUnit tool window?

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IDEA version 2021.3.2.

When I'm running tests, there's a few different patterns that I regularly want to highlight in the test output text.

I can do it by hand by doing a "Search" action (`Ctf`+`f`) and pasting in a regex like `given:|when:|then:|and:|mock` - this then highlights the matches in to output as shown in the screenshot.

Is there any way to configure IDEA to do this all the time?
Some kind of functionality to configure IDEA to permanently "highlight matches in JUnit output"?

[image]

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console/

Comment: You may try using [macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html), or any 3rd party snippets inserting program, such as https://github.com/lintalist/lintalist